# List of dictionaries using keys as headers & rows are the values of any data type

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv

** I'm currently tasked with creating a CSV file from a list of dictionaries where the headers are the dict keys and the rows the dict values but values should be any data type.**

```
store_value = [{'Key': 649.0, 'Folder': '/ANZ/', 'End Date': 44907.0, 'Depends On': '', 'Start Date Constraint': '', 'Description': '', 'Resolution / Update': '', 'Comments': 'Comment', 'Staging Link': 'https://', 'Retailer URL': '', 'Item Number': ''}, {'Key': 651.0, 'Folder': '/ANZ/', 'End Date': 44917.0, 'Depends On': '', 'Start Date Constraint': '', 'Description': ' https:', 'Resolution / Update': '', 'Comments': 'Approved', 'Staging Link': '', 'Retailer URL': '', 'Item Number': ''}]
```

```
f = open("test.csv", "a")
f.write(','.join(list(store_value[0].keys())))  # write headers
f.write('\n')

for i in store_value:
    print(type(i))
    f.write(','.join(list(i.values())))  # write values
    f.write('\n')

f.close()
```

**TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found**

Comment: You cannot *join()* floats or ints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot *join()* float or int.

Change this line:

```
f.write(','.join(list(i.values())))
```

...to...

```
f.write(','.join(map(str, i.values())))
```

Having said that, your entire program can be simplified thus:

```
import csv

store_value = [
    {'Key': 649.0, 'Folder': '/ANZ/', 'End Date': 44907.0, 'Depends On': '', 'Start Date Constraint': '', 'Description': '', 'Resolution / Update': '', 'Comments': 'Comment', 'Staging Link': 'https://', 'Retailer URL': '', 'Item Number': ''},
    {'Key': 651.0, 'Folder': '/ANZ/', 'End Date': 44917.0, 'Depends On': '', 'Start Date Constraint': '', 'Description': ' https:', 'Resolution / Update': '', 'Comments': 'Approved', 'Staging Link': '', 'Retailer URL': '', 'Item Number': ''}
    ]

with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=store_value[0])
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(store_value)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Fred it works but the data in not comes in proper way in csv file

Comment: @KunalJoshi Please edit the original question to show how the output appears in the CSV and explain why it's not what you wanted

Comment: Hi @Fred this was perfact expected given output. Very helpful for me. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error

> TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found

because  `.join()` method only works with strings. To solve this you can turn int into str. using `map(str, list(i.values()))`

```
Your final code should be:
    store_value = [{'Key': 649.0, 'Folder': '/ANZ/', 'End Date': 44907.0, 'Depends On': '', 'Start Date Constraint': '', 'Description': '', 'Resolution / Update': '', 'Comments': 'Comment', 'Staging Link': 'https://', 'Retailer URL': '', 'Item Number': ''}, {'Key': 651.0, 'Folder': '/ANZ/', 'End Date': 44917.0, 'Depends On': '', 'Start Date Constraint': '', 'Description': ' https:', 'Resolution / Update': '', 'Comments': 'Approved', 'Staging Link': '', 'Retailer URL': '', 'Item Number': ''}]
    f = open("test.csv", "a")
    f.write(','.join(list(store_value[0].keys())))  # write headers
    f.write('\n')
    
    for i in store_value:
        print(type(i))
        f.write(','.join(map(str, list(i.values()))))  # write values
        f.write('\n')
    
    f.close()
```